# how to grab the max from mysql columns and assign to php variable

Tags: php, mysql

It is giving me errors when I run this code, I want to grab the max of my columns then eventually add 1 to it.  I want to be able to use new max after these operations are completed.  I think my sytnax is wrong on the  x = line

```
     $sql2 = "SELECT max(order_number) from t_item_list
     where template_item_id =  '$id'"

     $x = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)
     $newmax = $x +1;
```

Comment: `$x` is an array. you can't do math with arrays like that, and you can't fetch from a query string. that's just some sql. it's useless until you EXECUTE it in the database.

Comment: [and this comes in when...?](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: [and you're using which...?](https://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing)

Comment: [and we should be...?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guessing)

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to execute the query. Here's your fixed code:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT max(order_number) from t_item_list where template_item_id = '$id'";

// I assume here that you already have a database connection
$result = $connection->query($sql2); 

$x = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$newmax = $x +1;
```

Also, `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` will probably return you an array. You must retrieve the value according to it.